# How to change the columns of a datatable according to select menu?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2 and PrimeFaces 5 I have a data table whose cell need to be updated according to the selection from drop down menu.To be specific  I want to change the list(dataTable value) based on my selection(basically this means for every option dataTable will show different records)?

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by just changing the model accordingly.

E.g. this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.changeDataModel}" update="table" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.dataModel}">
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

And in a `@ViewScoped` bean:

```
public void changeDataModel() {
    dataModel = someService.load(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @BalusC I have done this it work ... but I still have one problem:when I chose a value from the list I have table from items it size is exactly the number of items in each categorie but this table is free .. I have no value .. I don't know why O.o

Comment: I have it as @SessionScoped ..I change it but I have this error :\  deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI definition failure:WELD-000075 Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] public Bean.catBean.listCatégorie. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: I can resolve my problem this work so fine now ..thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. The details were just in the `server.log`, exactly as indicated by the exception.